# Download multiple file from controller

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, grails

I have this controller that let me download a file:

```
  File toDownload = new File("/tmp/" + fileName)
  response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
  response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=" + fileName)
  response.outputStream << toDownload.bytes
```

Now I need to download two files, and I have not idea how to do it, I'd like to avoid requesting it with a separate javascript call.

Answer (score 2):

There can only be 1 file per 1 HTTP request to consistently work within browsers.  If you want to send 2 files within a single request your best option is to zip up the 2 files and send the zip file in the payload.  Like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/zip")
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment;filename=\"someFileName.zip\"')
new ZipOutputStream( response.outputStream ).with { zos ->
   zos.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry( file1.name ) )
   zos << file1
   zos.closeEntry()
   zos.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry( file2.name ) )
   zos << file2
   zos.closeEntry()
   zos.finish()
}
```

But this will require a technically competent person to understand how to unzip the file to retrieve the original 2 files.

Another option is to return a static HTML page with multiple links they can use to request the files individually:

```
<html ...>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/url/to/file1">${file1.name}</a></li>
        <li><a href="/url/to/file2">${file2.name}</a></li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

The user would then click both links to retrieve the files individually.

The last option is to use javascript to request each file auto-magically for the user, but you had said you'd like to avoid that.

Comment: thank you @chubbsondubs I was wondering if I can achive the same result, without zipping, using  ContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace") with bounderies

Comment: @NiBE you cannot.  Chrome removed support for multipart/x-mixed-replace in 2014 except for images, and other browsers have spotty support for it.  This blog post shows how it might have worked long ago https://javadigest.wordpress.com/tag/multipartx-mixed-replace/ but sounds like it won't now.